# What is complexity of this code? (Big O) Is that linear?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, analysis, code-complexity

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length -1; i++){
  if(array[i] > array[i+1]){
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[i+1];
    array[i+1]=temp;
    i=-1;
  } 
}
```

I think the code sorts the input array and that its worst case complexity is O(n).

What is the correct big-O complexity of this code?

Comment: You're missing `}` and some indentation.

Comment: Yes thanks. But i am not asking that code is not working. I am asking complexity

Comment: I fixed your code to what I guess is your intention, since it makes sense as a bad implementation of bubble sort.

Comment: How can i sort my array in case O(n)?

Comment: There is a theorem that any comparison-based sort can't be done with better than O(n log n) comparisons. So unless there's some property of your array elements that you've omitted, it's impossible to sort an array in O(n) time.

Comment: Thanks. I want to ask you @PaulHankin
how can i sort my array while inserting new element? Firstly it is empty. When i add new item it will be sorted. Can i do this while inserting in O(n) time?

Answer (score 3):

It's O(n^3), and it's an inefficient version of bubble sort.

The code scans through the array looking for the first adjacent pair of out-of-order elements, swaps them, and then restarts from the beginning of the array.

In the worst case, when the array is in reverse order, the recurrence relation the code satisfies is:

```
 T(n+1) = T(n) + n(n-1)/2
```

That's because the first n elements will be sorted by the algorithm before the code reaches the n+1'th element. Then the code repeatedly scans forward to find this new element, and moves it one space back. That takes time n + (n-1) + ... + 1 = n(n-1)/2.

That solves to Theta(n^3).

Comment: What about the space complexity?

Comment: Space complexity is O(n), the space for storing the array of size n plus the negligible swap variable.

Comment: The space complexity is O(1). The space used by the input is not normally considered part of the space complexity.